# Rendezvous threads - thread doesn't finish processing when join() unblocks

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm going through the "Little Book of Semaphores" right now, and I'm having a problem with the first Barrier problem. In the below code , I'm trying to have 3 threads rendezvous before continuing. This part works fine - I always get 3 "before"s pushed to the queue. However, I don't always get 3 "after"s pushed to the queue. Sometimes I do, but not always. What am I doing wrong?

```
import threading
import random
import Queue
import time

num_loops = 1
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id, count, n, q, locks):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id = id
        self.q = q
        self.n = n
        self.locks = locks
        self.count = count
        return

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(random.random()/100)
        self.q.put("before")
        with self.locks['mutex']:
            self.count[0] += 1
            if self.count[0] == self.n:
                locks['barrier'].release()
        locks['barrier'].acquire()
        locks['barrier'].release()
        time.sleep(random.random()/100)
        self.q.put("after")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    total = 10
    incorrect = 0
    num_threads = 3
    for _ in range(total):
        q = Queue.Queue()
        locks = {'mutex': threading.Semaphore(1),
                 'barrier': threading.Semaphore(0),
                }
        threads = []
        count = [0]
        for i in range(num_threads):
            t = myThread(i, count, num_threads, q, locks)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)

        for i in threads:
            t.join()
            print "join"

        one_loop = ['before']*num_threads + ['after']*num_threads

        total_loop = one_loop * num_loops
        result = []
        while not q.empty():
            result.append(q.get())
        print result
        if result != total_loop:
            incorrect += 1
    print "%s out of %s is wrong" % (incorrect, total)
```

Comment: Although not useful here, there's always https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#barrier-objects

Comment: This is mostly just an academic exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. You do not join all the threads. The line:

```
for i in threads:
    t.join()
    print "join"
```

Should be:

```
for i in threads:
    i.join()  # changed line
    print "join"
```

Joining `t` is first just waiting for the last thread created, then in the rest of the iterations a no-op.

Comment: Nice catch. I would also like to point out the queue consumption is not safe in a multithreaded consumer environment. Between the call to q.empty() and q.get(), another thread could have grabbed the item, which would leave you blocking forever. In this case (draining a queue immediately) just keep calling q.get(False) until it throws.

Comment: Yikes! I thought this would be far more an interesting problem...Thank you.

Comment: I get that feeling too, sometimes. It's disappointing when you realise you just forgot to recompile your code...